# Magento 2: get latest Bestseller collection

Tags: collection, magento-2.2.5, best-seller, magento-ee

I am fetching Bestsellers like this:

```
protected $_collectionFactory;

\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,

$this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;

$bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
        ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
        ->setPageSize(8)
        ->setPeriod('month');
```

Issue is this that this is not giving me latest month entry first. 
I mean if in collection I have records from 2012 to 2018, I am getting first records of 2012. And as I need only 8 records so every time getting the same records.

Not getting how I can sort and get 2018 records first ?

Comment: Can you check the answer? Its working for me.

Comment: Hi Narendra, I am updating chirag's answer you should try ->setOrder('period','DESC')  like this.

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar: using so gives no error but records are not sorted

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
protected $_collectionFactory;

\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,

$this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;

$bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
        ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
        ->setPageSize(8);
```

Flush the cache and test.

Comment: I tried that and that works fine. But I need records month wise

Answer (score -1):

For that you need to get collection by descending order so you need to use `->setOrder('sort_order','DESC')` function.

Try with below code.

```
protected $_collectionFactory;

\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory 
$collectionFactory,

$this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;

$bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
    ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
    ->setPageSize(8)
    ->setPeriod('month')
    ->setOrder('sort_order','DESC');
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I am getting this error: Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sort_order' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(period, '%Y-%m') AS `period`, SUM(qty_ordered) AS `qty_ordered`, `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`.`product_id`, MAX(product_name) AS `product_name`, MAX(product_price) AS `product_price` FROM `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly` WHERE (rating_pos <= 5) AND (store_id IN(0)) AND (store_id IN(0)) GROUP BY `period`,
 `product_id` ORDER BY `period` ASC, `qty_ordered` DESC, sort_order DESC
 LIMIT 8

Comment: I think I need to change this ORDER BY period ASC to DSC. You have any idea how to do that ?

Comment: In the place of `sort_order` you need to pass `product_id`

Comment: For Ex:- if you wan to get last updates product so you need to pass like this `->setOrder('updated_at','DESC')`

Comment: G
etting same error for this as well. column not found

Comment: Try with `->setOrder('id','DESC')` OR `->setOrder('position','ASC');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87587/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-narendra).

Comment: not working for me :(

Comment: Same error you got?

Comment: For: setOrder('id','DESC') (no error but no change)... for  ->setOrder('position','ASC') (same erorr)

Comment: I think you missed something because in database data in stored `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly` table in table `id` is primary key if you sort by `id` then it have to work. but in your case i don't have idea why this is not working.
In short basically you need to load collection by descending order so you get latest record first.

Comment: Yes in my database table id exists. But on printing the collection there comes not id, i think this is the reason its not working. And I have not done any customizations yet.

Comment: I give you a way how to get latest bestseller collection now you have to find out how to sort order in descending order.